# How to filter crystal report so that if one JobID is ProductionComplete that all other jobID with the same first 5 digits will also be displayed

Tags: crystal-reports, suppress, startswith

I'm very new to crystal reports and my code issue isn't to complex, but I'm struggling find the right structure.

I have jobID's that all start with the same first 5 digits if they come from the same SalesOrderID.  the five digits they start with are the salesID number.

I want to display all of the JobIDs under a SalesOrderID if the production is complete on just one of them.

```
if {Jobs.jmpProductionComplete} =-1.00
 then
(
  If {Jobs.jmpJobID} startswith left({Jobs.jmpJobID},5)
  then {Jobs.jmpJobID}
  else  ""
)
```

but that produced a error saying "The result of selection formula must be a boolean"

Next I tried:

```
if {Jobs.jmpProductionComplete} =-1.00  then
(
  If {Jobs.jmpJobID} startswith left({Jobs.jmpJobID},5)
  then not(isnull({Jobs.jmpJobID}))
)
```

But that only displayed the single JobID that has been marked Production Complete.

Next I tried:

1. Created a formula with this code:
   left({Jobs.jmpJobID},5)
   named it @jobidformula
2. Go to the Group Expert > Move this formula to the Group List
3. Suppressed the Group Header and footer
4. Go to Report > Selection Formulas > Group and used this code:

   ```
   Minimum({Jobs.jmpProductionComplete}, {@jobidformula}) = -1
   ```

still didn't work.  Any other pointers anyone can give me?

Comment: I figured it out! 
I first made it so that my report only shows the JobIDs which production is complete grouped by salesOrderID
I made a subreport where the parameter was SalesOrderID 
and 
in the selection formulas I set it so that Production was not complete.
I lined them all up and vooila! It works without issue.

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out!**

I first made it so that my report only shows the JobIDs which production is complete grouped by salesOrderID

I made a subreport where the parameter was SalesOrderID

in the selection formulas I set it so that Production was not complete.
I lined them all up and vooila! It works without issue.